# How to create query that compares/ select the ID of another table

Tags: php, sql

Please help me in my problem I am searching this topic all over the internet and still i don't have the luck. to solve my problem..
..
...

So this the situation, I have 3 table 1 is `organization.tbl`, 2 is `candidates.tbl`, and 3 is `voters.tbl` so if the voters register and select 1 of the organization it uses that `id` of organization. so If the admin create the candidates and insert the organization that the same voters have.

I already created a column that has relationship with organization.tbl, candidates.tbl, voters.tbl and the org_id of candidates.tbl and voters.tbl is unique

my question is How to create query in php. ? If the `org_id` of voters is equal to `org_id` of candidates.tbl ?

this is my sample query for displaying the candidates

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM candidates INNER JOIN voters On voters.org_id = candidates.org_id  WHERE position='President' ");
```

and this is for the voters log in

```
    $login_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM voters INNER JOIN candidates On candidates.org_id = voters.org_id  
WHERE id_number='$id_number' and password='$password' and status='Unvoted'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You should take a look @ : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join

Comment: what type of join do you think ill use?

Comment: ill use left join for the second query

Comment: please help me to solve my problem

Comment: please include a simple of your database tables.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT  voters.voters_id, voters.org_id,  candidates.candidates_id, candidates.org_id, candidates.firstname, candidates.lastname, candidates.img
 FROM candidates INNER JOIN voters On voters.org_id = candidates.org_id  WHERE position='President' ");` i created quert like this and still i having hard time to display the candidates that equal to voters.org_id